# Automatically Assign Category for Invitations Where I am Optional

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, rules

I would like to configure Outlook 2010 such that when I receive an invitation for a meeting/event *where I am listed as optional* that a specific category is automatically assigned.  Is this possible?  How would I set this up as a rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are listed as optional in a meeting request, the message comes in with you in the CC field (required attendees are in the TO field).

You can set a rule with this description:

> Apple this rule after the message arrives
>   where my name is in the Cc box
>   and which is a meeting invitation or update
>   assign it to the < *whatever* > category